# React transclusion and communication with container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, transclusion

I'm looking for the proper pattern/way to develop this with React, but I didn't find anything relevant/elegant so far.

I basically want to write a form engine. For each input of the form, I want some generic behaviors.

I've read on React documentation that inheritance isn't the proper way to go; the good way to go is to design a generic component and specialize it by composition.

In my top component, I want to write something like:

```
<Form>
    <TextInput .../>
    <TextInput .../>
    <EmailInput .../>
</Form>
```

Each type of input must basically do always the same things: example: check this value against its validators, etc.

So, I've designed a generic component `FormInput` which contains all those standard behaviors. When I write my `TextInput` component, here is what it looks like:

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormInput>
                <input name={this.props.name} 
                       type='text'
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       onBlur={this.dirty}
                       value={this.state.value}
                />
            </FormInput>
        );
    }

}
```

Now, the trouble is that `this.onChange` or `this.dirty` are the standard behaviors located in the `FormInput` component, so obviously, I cannot access directly to them like that...

What is the proper way to connect the transcluded content to its container component?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify and sum up the goal, I basically want to make a generic component and a transcluded content/template. The issue with this is that I need to bind the specific DOM template (which is in the specific component) to the generic handlers (which are in the generic component).

Thanks by advance!

Comment: You want `FormInput` or `TextInput` to handle the changes and validations?

Comment: @Sagivb.g `FormInput` must host all the standard things like changes and validations. `TextInput` must basically only host the html `<input>` tag and its style.

Comment: So it seems like your hierarchy is wrong imo, `FormInput` should wrap `TextInput`.

Comment: It is very likely that my hierarchy is wrong! Could you provide a sample with the proper wrapping components?

Comment: Another question, shouldn't the `Form` handle the logic like `onChange` and `value` for each child `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out!

Here is my solution:

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    template(state, formInput) {
        return (
             <input name={this.props.name} 
                    type='text'
                    onChange={formInput.onChange}
                    onBlur={formInput.dirty}
                    value={state.value}/>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FormInput {...this.props} template={this.template} />
        );
    }

}
```

It was finally easier than expected, but I didn't use transclusion.

The `FormInput` component hosts everything, from the state to the common code/behaviors (like `dirty` or `onChange`).

The `TextInput` component only instanciates a `FormInput` and hosts a function called `template`, that takes the remote state and the generic `FormInput` component itself to access its functions.

Then in the `FormInput`, i've got the following:

```
render() {
    return this.props.template(this.state, this);
}
```

The generic input component calls the `template` function and passes in what is needed for the rendering.

This way, I uncouple the view from its behavior.

Hope you'll like it and that it will helps someone later ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your `onChange` and `dirty` methods are implemented inside FormInput component. In that case, the `input` element should be placed inside the render method of the component and not passed as children.

That `FormInput` render method should be something like this:

```
render(){
    return  <input name={this.props.name} 
                       type={this.props.type}
                       onChange={this.onChange}
                       onBlur={this.dirty}
                       value={this.state.value}
                />
}
```

Also `FormInput` should have name and type properties to use it this way:

```
 <FormInput name='A name' type='text' />
```

I guess, initially you were trying to have the possibility to pass also an input wrapped with other html elements. If that's the case, with my proposal, you simply can wrap the new FormInput to get the same result.

UPDATE:

To render other types of form elements inside the FormInput component, and if you don't feel comfortable with a conditional render, you can try other way, using `createElement` method inside the render with yout type prop.

More information here:
[Create Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

I used it before, and has worked pretty well on my projects.

Comment: That could work, unfortunately, this is quite a simplistic version here...                        `type={this.props.type}` will not be enough to cover any field: what if I want to implement checkboxes or radio buttons, or anything that needs a different DOM?

Comment: FormInput could use type prop to render any form element conditionally

Comment: This could work but it does not feel really pretty... I'm so disappointed that there is apparently no simple way to reach the container component...

Comment: I understand you :)
I updated the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> `FormInput` must host all the standard things like changes and validations. `TextInput` must basically only host the html `<input>` tag and its style.

It seems that your hierarchy is wrong In my opinion.
I would create an `Input` that responsible on how the primitive `input` should look and a `Form` that responsible on how the nested `input`'s should behave and what data they hold.

Here is a running example, obviously you can style it in other ways and not inline styles.

```js
const Input = ({ label, ...rest }) => (
  <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", margin: "10px 0" }}>
      <label style={{ minWidth: "100px", margin: "0 10px" }}>{label}</label>
      <input style={{ padding: "0.5em" }} {...rest} />
    </div>
  </div>
);

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    age: null
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    onSubmit(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    const { fName, lName, age } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="fName"
          label="First Name"
          value={fName}
          required
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="lName"
          label="Last Name"
          value={lName}
          required
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <Input
          type="number"
          name="age"
          label="Age"
          value={age}
          required
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={data => console.log(data)} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: The issue with this is the basically the same than @MiguelML's answer. Here, the `Input` component is not flexible enough: if I want to render checkboxes, or radio buttons, or a select, I won't be able to do that... That's why I would really like to have one component by input type, to split the DOM template from the generic component which would be located in another thing. Maybe my main mistake is that `FormInput` is a component... Maybe I should make/use something else than a component to host all the generic stuff.

Comment: I think your issue is that you are trying to generalize several primitives into one. `input` IS a `checkbox`, `radio`, `text` etc... but `select` is not an `input`. if you really want one component to render anything then you can conditionally render either an `input` (with relevant type) or a `select`. but in my opinion this component could have a terrible API, what would you pass it? `options`? `value`? `selectedValue`? `isOpen`? too generic is a flaw in my opinion

Comment: Yeah you are probably right and I'm trying to accomplish something too generic...